# jQuery Chosen.js - how to search in multiple select?

Tags: jquery-chosen

I'm using an jquery plugin called Chosen. I see it has a search option available for single select, does anyone know how I can enable it in a case of using multiple select?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, this is a dumb question. The multiple select has a 'auto complete' while typing in. why would I need the search still?! It normally take half an hour until my brain warms up in the morning... sorry.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Chosen search works with multiple select. Check examples on their site
http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

If you are asking, how to use it, here is the example:
Html code:

```
<select multiple class="chzn-select">
```

Javascript code:

```
$('.chzn-select').chosen();
```

And it is done.

Comment: Wow had the same question - the multiple select search isn't particularly obvious unless your placeholder is something like "Start typing [object]".

Answer (score 1):

For others who may be looking for a live demo there is a great fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RVH8D/ which shows a simple implementation of chosen and includes images in the results list.

If you want a multiple change

```
<select...>
```

to

```
<select... multiple="true">
```